# How to set mock data to an entity of context which has no key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-testing

Working with Integration tests in EF repository pattern,

Trying to set mock data for an entity context which is not having any primary key

In Tests.cs

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
        {
            _contextSetup = new ContextSetup();
            _context = _contextSetup.GetContext();
        }
```

```
class ContextSetup
{
 public DbContext GetContext()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyGenDb")
                .Options;
            return new DbContext(options);
        }
}
```

And when I am adding mock data as following

```
_context.MyGen.Add(new MyGen()
            {
                Name = "",
                Address = "",
                Locality = "",
                LoanPurpose = ""
            });
```

I am getting following exception
`Unable to track an instance of type 'MyGen' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.`

MyGen.cs

```
public class MyGen
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Locality { get; set; }
        public string LoanPurpose { get; set; }
    }
```

In DbContext.cs

```
public virtual DbSet<MyGen> MyGen { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyGen>().HasNoKey();
        }
```

What is wrong here ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: All entities must have a PK defined, even if the underlying database does not declare one. How else can it distinguish one row instance from another? You can declare a Key across as many columns as you need (including all of them) to distinguish a unique row.

Comment: @StevePy, I agree but I do not have any key for MyGen and I just loop over its rows to match the data, if exists then get the work done. So is there any way I can proceed ?

Comment: What is the consequence of marking all fields in the entity as [Key], or at least enough of them to uniquely differentiate rows from one another? Do you expect entirely duplicated rows in this table?